# how to change EditText background after editing and moving to next edittext

Tags: android

I have a form of multiple textfields/edittext . Wanted to change the background color of the edittext once I entered the data and moved to next form field.

Please suggest,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file `edittext_background.xml` in `drawable`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorEditTextDisable" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorEditTextFocusLost" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorEditTextFocusGained" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

And in add your desired colors in `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorEditTextDisable">#999999</color>
<color name="colorEditTextFocusLost">#ffffff</color>
<color name="colorEditTextFocusGained">#c6c6c6</color>
```

**TO USE BACKGROUNDS FROM DRAWABLES, TRY THIS ONE**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focus_lost" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focus_gained" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
</selector>
```

And set this as background to your `EditText` 
In XML: `android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"` 
Or in Java: `editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_background);`

Comment: I have one custom background structure used for each edittext. Can I add the same with this ?

Comment: @zeetmohanty Yes, of course. Instead of using colors, you can use drwables too. I'll suggest to create proper drawables for each state use them. Change `android:drawable="@color/colorEditTextFocusGained"` to `android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable_name"`

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it convenient for you.

Comment: Thanks Rehan. 've implemented ur code and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Lets sey you have edittext1 and edittext2:

`edittext1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));`

```
edittext2.requestFocus();
```

Comment: how to get that which edittext is finished the editing.

Comment: What does it mean "finished the editing"? if the user is editing the text you can't really know the time lol.. but if you pass text like edittext.setText("some text"); then you should add the code I wrote right after that.

Comment: I have 6 edittext fields on one page. Suppose I added some text in edittext1 and moved to next edittext. Then I wanted to change the background color of edittext1. Same process if I add some texts in edittext2 and moved to edittext3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `onFocusChangeListener` for each `EditText`. Now when the user clicks on another `EditText` and the focus is removed from the first one, `onFoucsChange` will be called  for the first `EditText` and you can change the background accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Piyush. This way works. But wondering I have to put same code many times for each EditText filed. Any way to reuse the same code by calling one method and passing the edittext as parameter.

Comment: Just implement the interface OnFocusChangeListener in your fragment and call edittext.onFocusChangeListener(this) for each EditText. This way there will be a single onFoucsChange in which you apply a switch or if-else to check view id and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

certin codes I have added with Rehan's code.Which gives the better functionality as web.

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(myEditTextFocus);

 private View.OnFocusChangeListener myEditTextFocus =  new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean gainFocus) {
            //onFocus
            if (gainFocus) {
                //set the text
                //((EditText) view).setText("In focus now");
                ((EditText) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_edittext);
            }
            //onBlur
            else {
                int l=((EditText) view).getText().length();//System.out.println("zeetu"+l);
                //clear the text
                if(l>1){((EditText) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_edit_text_new);}

            }
        };
    };
```